# Manage products page is broken - even after restore

Tags: admin, error, ce-1.9.0.1

[image: Manage product]
This is how the manage product page is broken.
All content on this page is shown in left sidebar even when I create new product.
I can't change products, I can't create them because I can't save any changes.

I'd wanted to restore 1 month old backup. I did complete restore, system files and database. All was working nicely. But then I restored whole database via phpmyadmin. The problem was back. I assume the issue is in the database.

Can I restore only "important" part of database - catalog, customers, orders..?

Does anybody know how to find what cause the problem? I started to be hopeless.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Not even magento 1.9.1.0 upgrade didn't help.

Comment: Try re-indexing and Flush Cache Storage!

Comment: I flushed everything what I could and re-indexed all as well..

Comment: I had added just those two but I deleted them.

Comment: I suppose that I started after I installed but I'm not sure

Comment: Check you javascript error console, it seem to be either  a javascript error or a module adding tabs incorrectly

Comment: TO me this looks like an issue with the custom admin theme you are using. It seems like the content is being added to the tab and not in content section. If you disable this theme does it fix the issue?

Comment: I have there javasript errors in prototype.js, I have already restored it from backup, but still.. Error in edited question.

Comment: I don't use custom theme. I have only colored header..

Comment: Not even magento 1.9.1.0 upgrade didn't help..

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**
Changes to core files being lost in a migration or upgrade can cause this issue. With the benefit of more experience with Magento and @Fiasco Labs comment, my simpler suggestion would be to look for modifications to core files in a project before migration, or really whenever you take over a project.  [Plugin provider Amasty offers a free tool](https://blog.amasty.com/freebie-magento-modified-core-files-report-by-amasty/) for checking for modified core files, or you can do it yourself by comparing the "core" folders in your site to those from a clean copy of your site's version of Magento.

**Original Answer**
I'm not sure if this will be helpful to the OP, but maybe it will help someone else.  I had this same problem with the catalog product edit page in the admin after migrating our site to a new server.

Based on @Manik's advice, I found that the project had a code file at `local\Ourproject\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Edit.php` that extended the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit` class. The contents of that file are below:

```
<?php

class Ourproject_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate('ourproject/catalog/product/edit.phtml');
        $this->setId('product_edit');
    }

}
```

Because I am not that familiar with how magento paths work, it took some looking around to figure out that I did not have the template file `ourproject/catalog/product/edit.phtml` on the new server.

I had followed the instructions from [the Magento wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/moving_magento_to_another_server) to migrate the site. That process has you copy over your database, create a new clean instance of Magento on your destination server, and then copy over only the files that should have been changed from your existing site.

I suspect that this issue arose because the custom `edit.phtml` file really should have been created at `app/design/adminhtml/ourproject/default/template/default/catalog/product/edit.phtml` instead of at `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/ourproject/catalog/product/edit.phtml`, and then would have been captured for migration following the instructions in the Wiki. Someone with greater experience may be able to weigh in on that.

Whatever the cause, bringing over the contents of the `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/ourproject` folder to the new server fixed this issue, and probably a few others I had not yet noticed.

Comment: So, basically **don't edit core files** if you want that particular migration method to work. Because the **missing modified file** was in the adminhtml default/default folder instead of the custom theme folder, it got missed and the backend broke.

Answer (score 0):

Its looks like css problem. Check your current magento `reset.css` and `boxes.css` files with the original files.

**Edited:**
So, Its not because of css .The class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs` responsible for your problem check this class with original magento file.

Comment: I compared it - no differences.

Comment: What about the other pages in admin.Is that pages shows correctly?

Comment: Yes, only manage products is wrong. I restored all adminhtml app and skin from backup. No changes..

Comment: I restored all in /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product from original. Still nothing changes

Comment: Its may be the theme you are using as said by @David Manners.

Comment: I do not use custom theme. It's built-in theme. I haven't changed anything but color of header, upload my logo and put link into header. That's all. I did this 3 months ago.. Now I have there completely original adminhtml app and skin as well.

Comment: What is happening if you clicked the tabs in left columns.Update your question with this.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your question. When I click on the tabs it opens the content underneath the tab. I will have to put the website into maintenance and restore two weeks old backup and then figure it out how to put everything back. Thanks anyway for your effort.