# Pack of 2 items with stock control

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, grouped-products, package

I want to sell packs of several items.

For example Pack 1 contains: item A which costs 5 USD and five times item B each for 2 USD. Price of this pack 1 would be 12 USD. Customer should not see none of it. He only should see Pack 1 for 12 USD.

I would make unique item for unique price but I need to check stock availability of item A and item B.

Can magento do it?

Comment: Please accept an answer if it helped you, so that the question counts as answered. We need a higher answer rate to get out of beta eventually. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you can achieve it with a bundle product with two options that have one selection with fixed amount each, so the customer cannot choose anything. Also set the price type to "fixed" instead of "dynamic" and set the bundle price to 12 USD, otherwise the customer will always see the individual prices of the parts.

You will still need to make some adjustments to templates and PDF generation if you want to hide the single items completely from the customer. At least:

- product page template
- bundle item template in cart, order, invoice

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'll use bundle or grouped item as soon as I solve my fail on Manage products page. If you have any idea how to solve this, I'd be so pleased. Thanks http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/41979/manage-products-page-is-broken

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just use a bundle or grouped item for this.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'll use bundle or grouped item as soon as I solve my fail on Manage products page. If you have any idea how to solve this, I'd be so pleased. Thanks http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/41979/manage-products-page-is-broken